# PHP Load Content From Div Via LoadHTML

Tags: php

i have some problems to retreive the HTML of a specefic div containing the class name "tabEmbed"

The code works but for some reason, it only returns the txt ... no HTML. All the text formating is striped out ... normaly there should be embed code as well. What did i miss?

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($Video_Source_HTML);
    $Div_Data           = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

    foreach($Div_Data as $Div) {
     if ($Div->getAttribute('id') === 'tabEmbed') {
      $Embed_HTML = $Div->nodeValue;
      if(preg_match('/<input type="text"(.*?)">/is', $Embed_HTML, $Embed)) {
       $Embed_Code = $Embed[1];
      }
     }
    }
```

Website Video Embed Code Source

```
      <div id="tabEmbed" class="tab">
        <h3 class="blackTitle">Embed this video to your site with this code:</h3>

        <input type="text" name="media_embed_code" id="mediaEmbedCodeInput" size="110" onclick="this.focus();this.select();" value="&lt;iframe src=&quot;&quot; frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;">
      </div>
```

$Embed_HTML Source:
Embed this video to your site with this code:

Comment: Do you mean `$Embed_HTML` is empty, while `$Embed_Code` is not? Also, you can simplify your code by using `DOMDocument::getElementById()` in stead of using `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()` like you're doing now — in proper, valid, HTML, there's only ever going to be one element with a certain id.

Comment: the problem is $Embed_HTML = $Div->nodeValue; is not show me all the codes from the div, is show just the text, how i can fix this problem ?

Comment: Why not just use getElementById instead of all that business with foreaching over all the divs?

Comment: i try $Div_test = $dom->getElementById('tabEmbed'); echo $Div_test->nodeValue; but still not show me the full html code from the div, is show just the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you can greatly simplify your code by using [`DOMDocument::getElementById()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) in stead of using [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php).

Then, if you're using a version of PHP equal to, or higher than 5.3.6, you can use [`DOMDocument::saveHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) to output the "outerHTML" of the node, like so:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML( $Video_Source_HTML );

// let's use getElementById() in stead of getElementsByTagName()
$div = $dom->getElementById( 'tabEmbed' );

// be sure to check your browser's source code, or output this as text/plain
echo $dom->saveHTML( $div );
```

And, as per [GordonM's helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432460/php-load-content-from-div-via-loadhtml/13432931#comment18363442_13432931), you could use [`DOMDocument::saveXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) in PHP versions before 5.3.6, to get acceptable results (depending on the actual content of the original HTML), like so:

```
echo $dom->saveXML( $div );
```

Comment: @MihaiViteazu You're welcome. When you feel you've received enough answers to your question, please be so kind to mark my answer as best (click the check mark) if you feel that my answer best solved your problem.

Comment: Below 5.3.6 I think you should still be able to get an acceptable result with saveXML() instead?

Comment: @GordonM Good point. Thank you, I took the liberty of adding this to my answer.

Comment: done thanks to all for the help, i can make something more better now then using just preg_match